# Excel Vba recursive Sub not changing Variant ByRef parameter

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, parameter-passing, variant

I have the following Sub getting a column of numbers into a Variant array than calling a Bubble sorting function on it to sort the numbers still in the Loo variable. I expect Loo to be changed i.e. numbers in it appearing in sorted order after the sorting function has received it Byref and has done its job. Interestingly the sorting happens, as a Watch shows on Inarray in the sorting function. But Loo - despite given ByRef to a Function - is never changed.

Are variant arrays not suitable for ByRef parameter passing? Am I doing something wrong in the sorter function? The Recursion is what "kills" Inarray before it can be written back to Loo?

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Loo As Variant

Public Destfile As Workbook

Private i As Integer

Sub sorter()
Set Destfile = Workbooks("SomeWB")

With Destfile.Worksheets("Somesheet").ListObjects("sometable").ListColumns("Numbers")
    Loo = Application.Transpose(.DataBodyRange)
End With

BubbleSortArray (Loo)


End Sub
```

The Bubble sorting Function is the following:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Private NumberOfChanges, p As Integer
Private Store As Variant

Public Sub BubbleSortArray(ByRef Inarray As Variant)

    NumberOfChanges = 0
        For p = 1 To UBound(Inarray, 1) - 1
        If Inarray(p) > Inarray(p + 1) Then

            Store = Inarray(p + 1)
            Inarray(p + 1) = Inarray(p)
            Inarray(p) = Store

            NumberOfChanges = NumberOfChanges + 1

        End If
    Next p

    If NumberOfChanges <> 0 Then BubbleSortArray (Inarray)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is caused by the parentheses around Loo in your call. VBA is different from other languages in that if a call to a routine does not have an assignment, parenthesis are not needed and in fact cause different behaviour. So:

```
BubbleSortArray (Loo)
```

more or less tells VBA to evaluate Loo before passing it to the sorting routine.

If you would call it like this, all would be well:

```
BubbleSortArray Loo
```

See for example this little demo:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 1
    bar (x)
    MsgBox x
    bar x
    MsgBox x
End Sub

Sub bar(ByRef x As Integer)
x = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! Just as You said: all got well after removing the parentheses. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are going to need to explicitly make Loo and Inarray arrays and not variants (you can make them arrays of variants...or Long, String, whatever).  Also not a great idea to have global or module-level variables.
Something like this will work:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub sorter()
    Dim Loo() As Variant
    Dim Destfile As Workbook

    Set Destfile = ThisWorkbook

    With Destfile.Worksheets("QueryResult").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("COLUMN_NAME")
        Loo = Application.Transpose(.DataBodyRange)
    End With

    Call BubbleSortArray(Inarray:=Loo)

    Stop
End Sub


Public Sub BubbleSortArray(ByRef Inarray() As Variant)
    Dim NumberOfChanges As Integer
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim Store As Variant

    NumberOfChanges = 0
        For p = 1 To UBound(Inarray, 1) - 1
        If Inarray(p) > Inarray(p + 1) Then

            Store = Inarray(p + 1)
            Inarray(p + 1) = Inarray(p)
            Inarray(p) = Store

            NumberOfChanges = NumberOfChanges + 1

        End If
    Next p

    If NumberOfChanges <> 0 Then BubbleSortArray Inarray:=Inarray

End Sub
```

Comment: The main reason for the failure in your code, however, was your recursive call to BubbleSortArray (with the parentheses) - it was trying to evaluate Inarray and therefore not passing by reference.  See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/byrefbyval.aspx and http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1004%20ByVal%20ByRef.shtml

Comment: @jkpieterse - I think that the call you reference is ok, since they use "Call," but the call within BubbleSortArrary to itself is the issue (sorry, can't comment on your answer since I don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Indeed, any calls with the parentheses were bad! The recursive and the calling of the BubbleSort also. Thank's for the links explaining the problem!

Comment: @Huaffa: In the original question, the keyword "Call" (in sub Sorter) was not used, hence my comment. I did miss the recursive call within the sort routine itself though.

Comment: @jkpieterse - you are right!  Sorry about that - not sure where I got it, unless I tested it in my end.  :)

Comment: I expect things like these might happen to people discovering the Call keyword is not needed and subsequently remove the keyword but leave the parentheses in place.